# 'function' object is not subscriptable when "include"ing Django URL pattern?

Tags: python, django, typeerror

I'm making a Django website, off of a tutorial I'm watching on http://youtube.com, and I'm having problemos. Here's my urls.py script:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^', include['FirstBlog.apps.homepage.urls']),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'FirstBlog.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^FirstBlog/', include('FirstBlog.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And my output:

```
TypeError at /
'function' object is not subscriptable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'function' object is not subscriptable
Exception Location: /Users/thor/Sites/FirstBlog/FirstBlog/urls.py in <module>, line 8
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/thor/Sites/FirstBlog',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 2 May 2012 17:42:04 -0500
```

Please help?

Also, if you have a good tutorial I could follow, please link me it! Also, I would preferably like to use Mamp Pro for the databases. Help a n00b?

Comment: So, there is a function named by `include` and `[...]` is being use on it. Don't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`include` is a function; you're subscripting it as if it was a list.

For example:

```
apples = [ 'Granny Smith', 'Russet' ]
red_apple = apples[1]    # <-- Subscripting a list
```

Since functions can't be subscripted, you get the error you posted. But, as can be seen in the commented examples, you should be *calling* the function using the `()` syntax:

```
(r'^', include('FirstBlog.apps.homepage.urls'))
#             ^                              ^
```

Comment: Thank you! NOW, TO TEXT MATEEEE!