# Django throwing a strange error suddenly

Tags: python, django

It was working all fine until a couple of weeks ago when I last pushed an update. Today, I suddenly started getting this error. Tried to reinstall python, rollback django's version. Even tried removing all the urls except admin from urls.py. However, not seems to be working. Please help if someone has seen this before.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns[
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^sendd_auth/', include('sendd_auth.urls'))
]
```

sendd_auth/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

__author__ = 'vatsalshah'

urlpatterns = patterns[
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
]
```

Here is the traceback:

```
[2015-09-18 23:47:57] ERROR [django.request.handle_uncaught_exception:256] Internal Server Error: /admin/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 394, in urlconf_module
    return self._urlconf_module
AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 119, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 366, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 402, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/senddNXT/senddNXT/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    url(r'^sendd_auth/', include('sendd_auth.urls'))
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/senddNXT/sendd_auth/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
[18/Sep/2015 23:47:57]"GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 107863
[2015-09-18 23:47:57] ERROR [django.request.handle_uncaught_exception:256] Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 394, in urlconf_module
    return self._urlconf_module
AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 108, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 74, in process_request
    if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 647, in is_valid_path
    resolve(path, urlconf)
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 522, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 366, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 402, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/senddNXT/senddNXT/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    url(r'^sendd_auth/', include('sendd_auth.urls'))
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/virtualenvs/senddNXT_python343/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/vatsalshah/Developer/senddNXT/sendd_auth/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please post your entire `urls.py`

Comment: Please show the full sendd_auth/urls.py.

Comment: Have you tried the string path version of the view func?  I.e. 
"django.contrib.auth.views.login"?  On import is that login a function?  Seems to me it is reacting to it as a string.

Comment: Every time I say "but I didn't change *anything*" it turns out I had. Every time someone else has come to me with a "but I didn't change anything" problem it turns out that they had. This is running in a virtualenv in your personal directory; something was changed.

Comment: @msw - The only thing I suspect might have changed is pyenv. I remember updating the version for that.

Comment: @JLPeyret - Let me try that

Comment: Re the missing attrib in 2nd exception. Note **self._urlconf_module** assignment somewhere in first exception. So didnt happen, may be why not found later.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422822/function-object-is-not-subscriptable-when-includeing-django-url-pattern

Comment: @JLPeyret - Still the same error with string path version :(

Comment: @JLPeyret - I checked the link. However, I already have the `include` in that format.

Comment: Yeah, but google all the **object is not subscriptable django url**.  so many hits.  Different reasons.  But frequent error.  Besides, you use 2 include formats in urls.py. Str and function.

Comment: @JLPeyret - I tried most of them before posting here. None of the solutions work in my case. Most of them ask to use include in the () format I'm already using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused two syntaxes here - the old deprecated `patterns(...)` and the new standalone `[]` version. You have `patterns[...]` which is why Python is complaining that you're trying to subscript a function.

Just drop the word `patterns`.